# When using upload type everything goes well, when using upload_multiple getting error

Tags: laravel-backpack

when using this: `CRUD::field('photos')->type('upload')->withFiles(['path' => 'productphotos']);`. it upload the images to the /productphotos directory in the public storage.

When trying to change that to `CRUD::field('photos')->type('upload_multiple')->withFiles(['path' => 'productphotos']);` on submit I am getting this error: `Too few arguments to function Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\Uploaders\Uploader::getPreviousFiles(), 0 passed in vendor/backpack/crud/src/app/Library/Uploaders/MultipleFiles.php on line 22 and exactly 1 expected`

Does anyone know how to fix this error so I can continue? I've already tried to only use the settings from the Laravel Backpack docs but still get this error.

Thanks

EDIT:
Version:

```
### BACKPACK PACKAGE VERSIONS:
backpack/basset: 1.0.0
backpack/crud: 6.0.4
backpack/generators: v4.0.0
backpack/permissionmanager: 7.0.0
backpack/theme-coreuiv2: 1.1.3
```

ProductModel

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;

class Product extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_id',
        'price',
        'weight',
        'quantity',
        'stock_control',
        'notes',
        'age_restricted',
        'sale_item',
        'active',
        'list_index',
        'photos'
    ];

    public function category() : BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an bug in Laravel Backpack which is gonna be fixed in version 6.0.6

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).